# How do you execute multiline query in python mySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to execute this query in SQL using MySQL and python

**The SQL**

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE temporder SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE mealname=("Chicken Chow Mein")
```

**My Python/MySQL implementation**

```
setSQL="""SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;"""
mycursor.execute(setSQL)
mydb.commit()
updateQuantitySQL="""UPDATE temporder SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE mealname=%s"""
mycursor.execute(updateQuantitySQL,(selectedItemData[0]))
```

**Resulting Error**

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

I have isolated the error down to the line:

```
updateQuantitySQL="""UPDATE temporder SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE mealname=%s"""
```

But when I execute the SQL in the Workbench it works correctly, (however SQL_SAFE_UPDATES must be set to 0)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `mycursor.execute(updateQuantitySQL,(selectedItemData[0], ))` .. notice the comma

Comment: To elaborate on the comment posted by @Umair, your parameter list needs to be just that, either a list or tuple. `(7)` is *not* a tuple; it is just a parenthesized expression. `(7,)` *is* a tuple.